# VS Code | View Serial Monitor Toggle Command

Tags: visual-studio-code, serial-monitor

I am using VS Code with arduino extension which has Serial Monitor Window.
To toggle that window right now I have to do Ctr+Shift+P and then select View: Toggle Terminal. which only works if I have Terminal and Serial Monitor on Same panel.

But I want to use Shortcut Menu bar to do the same and it needs command there so how do we find which command actually used to toggle Serial Monitor view?

Comment: what is the `Shortcut Menu bar`

Comment: is "View: Serial Monitor Toggle" the exact name of the command? no typo?

Comment: ShortCut Menu Bar - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerrygoyal.shortcut-menu-bar

@starball -- You are right currently I am using Toggle Terminal Command.

Comment: I'm confused. the extension you linked to already has "toggle terminal" in its documentation. if you want to use toggle terminal, it should already be available through that extension. so what's the problem?

Comment: @starball - only Few icons visible on bar - https://prnt.sc/Patr7PtTXBZe
I can add custom Button and put command inside so that button comes on this bar no need to go three dots and then select toggle terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can find all commands name on the [extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino)

In you case the command is `arduino.openSerialMonitor`

Comment: It does open SerialMonitor in listen mode. What I wanted was actually the way we can toggle the view of Terminal in vscode which hides terminal and brings up when we click toggle.